# Examples using javascript to run a GET on another URL, retrieve the xml returned and look up a specific node?

Tags: javascript, xml, url

How would I get an xml document from a particular url in javascript then look up a particular sub node and get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery it's really easy because you an 'query' the XML document like you would with an X/HTML document.

Let's say you had a simple xml document like this...

```
<book>
  <title>Catcher in the Rye</title>
  <author>J.D. Salinger</author>
</book>
```

You can use jQuery to load the document and parse out particular nodes.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.get("/book.xml", function(responseXml) {
            var xml = $(responseXml);
            var title = $("title", xml).text();
            var author = $("author", xml).text();

            alert(title); // >> Catcher in the Rye
            alert(author); // >> J.D. Salinger
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And vivin makes a great point about loading xml from an external domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to make an AJAX call to the url, as long as it's on the same domain (AJAX has same-origin policy). Also, take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_examples.asp) for some tips on manipulating XML in Javascript.

If you are using jQuery, you can use `jQuery.ajax` and set the datatype to `XML`.

If your XML resides on another URL (i.e., not on your domain), then things get trickier. You'll need to use something server-side (like PHP, ASP, or JSP's) that generates a Javascript file that contains the XML (which it grabs from the URL) stored in a string. Then, in your page you'll need a script tag that points to this Javascript file.